# How can I enable commenting from mobile view?

Tags: comments

EDIT: as noted in the comments to the answer below. there isn't really a problem. The link for commenting is just small and easy to miss. It is there though.

I use theme 2016 on wordpress 4.7.3. Basic, but it does most of what I want.

I like getting comments from the people that read my blog.

The thing is, I don't think there's a way to submit a comment from a mobile device.

Is there a way to add either a menu item or something at the foot of the post to enable comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed the theme myself and resized down to mobile, the comment form seems to still be there for me. What can you see? Can people leave comments on the desktop?

Comment: of course, like heisenberg, asking the question cause things to work. mostly. I end up with a link "leave a comment", tucked in between the current post and the next. Not quite as obvious as a comment form, so I didn't notice it. If I go to the permlink for the post, there's the form. I'll probably delete the question as there isn't really a problem.  Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: No problem, i thought some css was maybe hiding it on the media queiry for a mobile. Glad to know its fine.